# Three.JS: Weird flicker/render with transparent MeshPhongMaterial

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm having the following Mesh in my scene:

```
const cylinder = new Mesh(
  new CylinderGeometry(2, 2, 1, 32),
  new MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: color,
    shininess: 32,
    opacity: 0,
    transparent: true,
    specular: 0xffff82,
  }),
);
```

Because I want to fade each circle in, I made the Mesh transparent. When I move my camera there is some weird rendering and I have no clue why this happens or what I need to change. As soon as I remove transparent it'll work just fine.

[image]

EDIT

Here is a fiddle showing the problem. Line 139 in css is where the cylinders get created.
**https://jsfiddle.net/mxmtsk/tb6gqm10/35/**

Comment: Can you make a fiddle showing the problem?

Comment: @GarrettJohnson i have added a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some faces of the transparent cylinders disappear behind the plane. You can easily fix this by slightly move the cylinders towards the camera like so:

```
cylinder.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2; 
cylinder.position.z = 0.5; // fix
```

In this way, the cylinders do not intersect with the plane.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f8m1u4rg/

Comment: Thanks, I try to understand better what happened exactly. If i only move the camera and not the cylinder and plane - how can they disappear behind the plane?

Comment: What you see is a transparency problem. Since an instance of `ShadowMaterial` is transparent by default, all objects in your scene are organized in the same render list and thus sorted together. Normally, all cylinders are rendered after the plane. If you change the position of the camera, this not true anymore and it produces the mentioned artifact. Rendering transparent objects does only work in this case when all objects are rendered in back-to-front manner and the geometries do not intersect.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation